# I can't get the id while we scraping (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my first post. Hope to be clear.

I'm scraping a web-site and here is the code I'm interested to scrape:

```
<div id="live-table">
    <div class="event mobile event--summary">
        <div elementtiming="SpeedCurveFRP" class="leagues--static event--leagues summary-results">
            <div class="sportName tennis">
                <div id="g_2_ldRHDOEp" title="Clicca per i dettagli dell'incontro!" class="event__matchevent__match--static event__match--twoLine">
                   
                 ...
```

What I would like to obtain is the last id (`g_2_ldRHDOEp`) and here is the code I produced using the beautifulsoup library

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '...'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent, 'html.parser')

list = []
list = soup.find_all("div")
total_id = " "

for i in list :
    id = i.get('id')
    total_id = total_id + "\n" + str(id)

print(total_id)
```

But what I get is only

```
 live-table
 None
 None 
 None
 None
```

I'm quite new both to python and beautifulsoup and I'm not a seriuos programmer, I do this just for fun.
Can anyone answer me why can't I get what I want and may be how I could do this in a better and succesful way?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `list` and `id` are built-in functions. you should not use these as names. What you expect to get? from first 4 `div` tags only first `div` has `id` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, there were 4 None, even for the last div even if it has a proper id. And for the naming you are right. sorry, my bad.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. I get 2 ids and 3 None and one blank line at the start - as expected. Of course the code can be simplified a lot, but anyway - it works for me.

Comment: What's the actual url? The page may be dynamic

Comment: this is the url: https://www.flashscore.it/giocatore/djokovic-novak/AZg49Et9/
to be clear, i'm interested in the last played game of Djokovic.

I know I can simplify the code but how? this is the first day coding in py ahah I need some tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) are built-in functions, so don't use them as variable names.

---

The website is loaded dynamically so `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.flashscore.it/giocatore/djokovic-novak/AZg49Et9/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("div", id="g_2_ldRHDOEp"):
    print(tag.get_text(separator=" "))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
30.10. 12:05 Djokovic N. (Srb) Sonego L. (Ita) 0 2 2 6 1 6 P
```

Comment: First of all thank you.
Some questions: Why I need such driver? and why did you decided to sleep(5)?
Anyway thank you a lot!

Comment: @Gabrielek 1. Since the page is loaded dynamically so `request` doesn’t support it. 2. `sleep` was used to wait for the page to fully load before scraping it.